# Path Integral using Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Am revising Complex Analysis, and have come across this equality:

For $R\gt 1$ and $|a|\lt 1$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma (0;1)}\frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-a} dz = \overline{\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma (0;1)}\frac{{f(z)}}{z(1-\overline{a}z)} dz}$$

And this supposedly follows from the Cauchy Integral Formula, that $$f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma (w;r)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz$$

But I just can't see how to apply this to get the desired result?

If someone could explain it to me, that would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: tripos? I think this comes from considering a "greens function" type point outside the counter of integration, and noting the CIF of that point vanishes, so can be added on without changing the original integral

Comment: Where is $f$ defined? Where is it analytic? What is $\gamma(0,1)?$ We're not mindreaders here. (Also note: "revising" should be "reviewing".)

Comment: Revise is the word used here in the UK to mean "prepare for an examination"